# Cookie value is necessary to invalidate session when requesting logout via /connect/logout

Tags: spring-authorization-server

When sending the following request, the request is successfully finished but the login screen is still skipped. The user doesn't need to login again.

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/connect/logout' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'id_token_hint={id_token_hint}' \
--data-urlencode 'post_logout_redirect_uri=https://example.com'
```

Only when sending request with the Cookie, the login screen is presented again.

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/connect/logout' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'id_token_hint={id_token_hint}' \
--data-urlencode 'post_logout_redirect_uri=https://example.com'
-H "Cookie: JSESSIONID={sessionId}"
```

Could the session be invalidated based on `id_token_hint` and not the Cookie value?

I found in the class `OidcLogoutEndpointFilter`, the logout is performed based on the provided Cookie, so if cookie is not found, the session cannot be invalidated.